# Файл .config строка подключения как спрятать?

Tags: c#, winforms, config

В программе строка подключения была прописана в каждой форме, после совета на этом сайте я запихнул ее в App.config и теперь это выглядит так :

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString))
```

Когда я перекомпилюваю прогу рядом с ней выпадает файл имяПриложения.exe.config,и если открыть блокнотом, в этом файле прописана строка подключения с логином паролем именем бд и тд. . Если рядом с прогой файл не лежит прога не работает, как быть? Переписать снова строку подключения в каждой форме ручками, или есть решения, может кодировка подскажите пожалуйста. Ведь любой может подключится к БД используя то что там прописано.

Comment: [Насколько я понимаю](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29177724/276994), вы можете воспользоваться [этим советом](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178372.aspx), если временно переименуете `app.config` в `web.config`.

Comment: @VladD наверно я все таки создам `public` переменную в `static` классе и пихну ее во всех участках кода где это необходимо... Потому что приведенные вами решение пичаль тоска..

Comment: Ну это да. Смысл писать в конфиг тот, что его можно менять между запусками. Если это не нужно, статическое поле наверное не самое плохое решение.

Comment: А также любой может использовать декомпилятор, чтобы выдрать строку подключения из вашей константы. Ограничивайте права доступа на уровне БД.

Comment: @andreycha есть способ защитится от этого?

Comment: Обфускация. Но я вам намекаю, что вы не в ту сторону идете.

Comment: @andreycha ПО использует общего пользователя для доступа к БД, этот пользователь владеет всеми правами, так как от его имени ведет удаление\добавление\редактирование инфы в БД. Если кто то с не хорошими мыслями вытащит строку подключения и подключится к БД хана..

Comment: А почему хана? Фактически пользователь Вашей программы работает с этой БД от имени общего пользователя. Работает он через эту программу или еще как подключится - фактически права во всех случаях полные.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как уже сказали в комментариях, строка подключения в любом случае может быть получена злоумышленником если она находится в файле конфигурации или коде программы. Обфускация может немного замедлить этот процесс, но не остановить.

Есть и еще один минус прямого обращения к БД из приложения - необходимость предоставлять доступ к серверу БД из внешней сети, со всеми вытекающими проблемами безопасности.

Однако есть способ не выставлять сервер наружу и не передавать в приложение строку подключения, но потребуется дополнительная работа. Если это не пугает - читаем дальше.

Для безопасной работы с БД необходимо:

- вынести функции доступа к БД в сервис WCF;
- в контракте сервиса определить необходимые методы, которые будут доступны приложению;
- настроить привязку приложения к сервису.
- все функции приложения работы с БД выполнять только через вызовы соответствующих методов сервиса.

Работы много, а что взамен?

- WCF сервис может размещаться на сервере доступном из внешней сети и иметь прямой доступ к изолированному во внутренней сети серверу БД. То есть фактически будет выполнять роль шлюза.
- Приложение может обращаться только к методам сервиса, при этом не имея возможности видеть какие именно команды скрыты за методами сервиса.
- Приложению не требуется строка подключения к БД. Приложение вообще не знает что оно работает с БД, он работает с сервисом.
- При правильной обработке параметров в методах сервиса, исключены SQL-инъекции, т.к. никакого SQL-кода не передается, весь SQL инкапсулирован в сервисе. (да, при кривой реализации SQL-инъекцию можно пропихнуть и через WCF)
- сам по себе сервис достаточно легкий, сточки зрения потребления системных ресурсов, и можно одновременно держать 2 и более сервисов для приложений разных версий, которые при этом работают с одной и той же БД.

А недостатки?

- Необходимость изучения новой технологии. WCF довольно мощное средство и для эффективного использования придется погрузиться немного глубже примеров кода на MSDN и решений на SO, но для быстрого старта хватит и этого.
- Дополнительные усилия на разработку публичного контракта и самого сервиса.
- Для добавления нового функционала в большинстве случаев потребуется вносить изменения в приложение и сервис одновременно, но тут как обычно все зависит от архитектуры, если архитектура нормальная, то сильной головной боли не будет.
- WCF имеет некоторые технологические ограничения, некоторые обойти можно, некоторые нет, в частности, будет сложно (но не невозможно) передать большие наборы данных возвращаемые запросом к базе.
- Любая дополнительная прослойка увеличивает время отклика, сложность системы и количество возможных ошибок, которые придется вылавливать и исправлять